# Working with Socket.io sending and receiving objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is my app.js file

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('ujwal', function (data) {
    socket.emit('news', function(){
        console.log('testing');
    });
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
});
```

On ujwal event i am emitting another event to the client 
here is my index.html i have included socket lib too

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    $('#test').click(function(){

        var as = "object";
        socket.emit('ujwal',as);


    });

    socket.on('news', function (a) {
        alert('receiving msgs');
    });
```

Now i am opening two windows whenever a user click a test id they are getting but who are not clicking they are not receiving the object in front end why? why code means whenever u get name event ujwal please fire news A and B are connected to server A click the test ujwal is fired and checking by server and again send back news now all the user connected should see the alert ?

This what i know so please make it work so that all user can get alert.

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using?  Are you getting any javascript errors prior to the event firing?

Comment: its 1.3.5 no any error when i click test i am getting back object but when u click the test i and u should get object back but its not happening i dont know whats wrong with code or logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `socket.emit()`, you're emitting directly to that socket, not all sockets. To emit to all sockets, emit from `io`

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('ujwal', function (data) {
        //socket.emit('news', function(){
        io.emit('news', 'some message');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry to tell its not working the error i am getting is                                      Missing error handler on `socket`.
user disconnected
Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting .

Comment: @ujwaldhakal wonder if it has something to do with the fact that you're  emitting a function instead of a message.

Comment: I am justing testing here now if it has news event then in client side all connection will check for the news if there is news then alert will pop up in everyone's screen. Dont know whats i am doing wrong here.

Comment: remove the callback you're passing to .emit().

Comment: As a matter of fact, that's exactly the issue. See the source here: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L138

Comment: Kevin B Thank your for ur support io.emit doesnt accepts closure passing the 2nd argument works. Learned !

Comment: Seems like the rule is the last argument can't be a function. Not entirely sure what would happen if the 2nd to last one was a function, and not sure why you would pass a function anyway.

Comment: Simply i am learning this socket.io module now nvm i can pass object as 2nd param :)